# devops using Ajax access query data WIQL

Tags: azure-devops, devops, agile, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to access azure-devops data using Ajax. And below is my working code.

```
 $.ajax({
            url: 'https://dev.azure.com/ORG/products/_apis/wit/workitems/2065741?$expand=all&api-version=5.1',
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa("" + ":" + 'XXXX')
            }
        }).done(function( results ) {

        });
```

After I need to access data using WQIL but it is giving an unexpected token error. I want to access WorkItem, and user activity. Can you please help with this?

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'https://dev.azure.com/ORG/products/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=5.1 ',
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa("" + ":" + 'XXXX')
            },
            JSON.Stringfy("QUERY":"SELECT     [System.Id],    [System.WorkItemType],    [System.Title],    [System.AssignedTo],    [System.State],    [System.Tags] FROM workitemLinks WHERE " +
    "(         [Source].[System.TeamProject] = @project        AND [Source].[System.WorkItemType] = 'User Story'      )     AND (         [System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward'    ) "+
    " AND (         [Target].[System.TeamProject] = @project         AND [Target].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Task'     ) ORDER BY [System.Id] MODE (MustContain)")
        }).done(function( results ) {
         x=results
        });
```

Comment: Hi, how the things going? Does the below script sample could help you achieve access Azure decvops with WIQL in Ajax successfully now?  If yes, you can accept the answer thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works. If you still facing some issues, feel free to leave commend here thus I could continue to help you:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow WQIL is giving error 400 it looks like a permission issue.

So I Solved it in a different way. Instead of the query, there is another method which gives me all the details of the workitem I just need to pass workitem Id's in that.

```
 var d ={
  "ids": [
    20813,21677
  ],
  "fields": ["System.Id","System.WorkItemType","System.Title","System.AssignedTo","System.State","System.Tags"]
};
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'https://dev.azure.com/ORG/products/_apis/wit/workitemsbatch?api-version=5.1',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(d),
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("" + ":" + "XXXXX"));
                },
            }).done(function (data) {
               x=data
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous script you are using is the method used to execute API, but not **suitable** for execute WIQL script. That's why you are facing that error.

Executing `WIQL` in `Ajax` is actually a **request** process: **Send the `wiql` statement to the server you want to access, request to execute the query statement(Wiql), and return the execution result.** Therefore, this is a process of requesting the execution of the `Post` command. But in your script, it did not tell the server what instructions need to be executed.

Here is the simple sample can for you refer to use `WIQL` with `Ajax`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#SelectWIT").on("click", function () {
            var d = { "query": " Select [System.Id] from WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'Bug' "};
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=1.0',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(d),
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("" + ":" + "{PAT token}"));
                },
            }).done(function (data) {
                var items = [];
                $.each(data.workItems, function (key, val) {
                    items.push("<li> <a href='" + val.url + "'>" + val.id + "</a></li>");
                });

                $("<ul/>", {
                    html: items.join("")
                }).appendTo("body");
            }).error(function (e) {
                var s = "error error error";
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

The logic of my script is to request to run a API with a **WIQL** statement as request body, send this request to the project I want to access. Then display the response data with `js` syntax into the body of the page. This is the output:

[image]
Since I am not sure what is your next operation. You can replace the Wiql statement and the Url with yours in this script. Then change the corresponding done function to achieve what you want.

Comment: @JigarParekh 400 means bad request, there should some error on the request body. Can you tell me where did you change based on my script ?

Comment: I have just modified {org name}/{project name} and my token

Comment: @JigarParekh, :( wired. Can you update any screenshots about the error message? Better include your completed script.

Comment: not able to add big comment, not able to see optino to add screenshot, and no option for chat here. you know how to add screenshot in comment ?